# Overlay background is getting covered by other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to play around with some basic coding and I have an issue with an overlay, here's a link: http://createak.co.il/
I apologize for the strange language. :-)
When you click on the button with the tiny you will see that this overlay form isn't functioning properly. I tried to play around with Z-index but it didn't seem to work.
Moreover, you can see that the fields aren't centered although they should be. I wonder what's preventing it from being aligned to the center.
Any ideas how to sort this thing out?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean the green button is not inline with the white buttons?

Comment: It's hard for me to tell from looking at the link what isn't working properly. The overlay is coming down from the top in chrome, and the elements are centered.

Comment: What isn't work properly? It could be nice know what you expect.

Comment: Do note, that for `z-index` to work, the element need a position other than `static`, that said, you need to post a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue, as external links is no good since they tend to die, and when they do, this question will be useless to future users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Even though your "myNav" has high z-index it's itself positioned inside "elementor-widget-wrap" with z-index of "1". If you remove the z-index from "elementor-widget-wrap" it will work fine, or you could add

```
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
```

to the section tag you have your myNav in.
Like this:

```
.elementor-7 .elementor-element.elementor-element-jnflk99 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

2) The text inputs of the form are not aligned because they have `width: 96%;` it should be `100%`. (Rule `#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group` at line 13 in http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css)

Comment: Hey, thanks!
Second suggestion worked fine. I tried adding to the Custom CSS file: 
.elementor-widget-wrap {
position: relative !important;
z-index: 999 !important;
} but it didn't work.

Comment: Don't know what generates random strings like "jnflk99" but as long as it stays the same the rule will work, look at the updated answer.

Comment: Don't know if I'm doing anything wrong, but I tried your suggestion (You can see it in the code), yet it still didn't work. :-(

Comment: Where have you added the .elementor-7 .elementor-element.elementor-element-jnflk99 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
} rule? Can't see it.

Comment: Okay I got it to work now, but there's this tiny annoying white line at the bottom of my browser if I hover the button and unhover it. It happens in the overlay. Do you see it too? Any idea what's the white thing covering my overlay?

Comment: Used to, but seems like you fixed it.

Comment: I have no idea what I did... Somehow it was just solved. Thanks for everything!